# Lie brackets of extensions of vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

If $M$ is a smooth manifold and $X$ is a vector field defined on $M$ and $W$ is a vector field defined on an embedded submanifold $S$, my question is:
$[X,\tilde{W}]|_S$ does not depend by extension? where $\tilde{W}$ is an extension of $W$. (I thinks so but I can't prove it.)

Thanks for all help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it depends. For example, consider the projection $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^1, (x,y) \mapsto x$ and $X=\partial_{x}$. For $W=\partial_{y}$ along $x=0$, take two extensions $Y=(1+x)\partial_{y}$ and $Y'=(1+x^2)\partial_{y}$. The restriction to $x=0$ for $[X,Y]$ and $[X,Y']$ are $\partial_{y}$ and $0$ respectively.

Comment: If I take  two vertical extensions, It does not depend. Right?

Comment: If two vector fields are tangent to a submanifold $S$, let's say $X, Y \in \Gamma(TS)$, and if $X', Y'$ are extensions of $X$ and $Y$ to $M$, then $[X',Y']|_{S}=[X,Y]$. I think this is the more general result you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It definitely depends on the extension. Think of the coordinate expression for the Lie bracket: it involves the derivatives of the components of both vector fields *in all directions*. That means that its value at a point $p$ depends on the behaviour of the fields in a whole neighborhood of $p$, and not only in the directions tangent to the submanifold.

Comment: Oh, sorry I forgot to write some things. I edit now.

Comment: You should never ask a question which is fundamentally different than what you really want to know. I suggest you start a new question instead of editing.

Comment: True. I do it. Sorry.